# How to navigate a large Dataset with keyboard short-cuts?

Tags: front-end, dataset, customization

**Update** : Starting in 11.1 the navigation buttons are fixed to the left-hand side instead of being centered and don't jump around anymore.

---

Starting with version 11.0 `Dataset` has a very nice interface for navigating.  The problem is that cells in my records are of varying width so the navigation buttons jump around as I page through the `Dataset`.  This is very unwieldy and can result on the wrong button being clicked.

Is there a way to navigate an `Dataset` with the keyboard.  Perhaps the arrow-keys.  A minimal example `Dataset` to practice the solution on follows.

```
SeedRandom[1234]
MapIndexed[IntegerName[First@#2] -> #1 &, 
   AssociationThread[{"a", "b"}, #] & /@ ({#, Range[#]} & /@ 
      RandomChoice[Range[10, 1, -1] -> Range[10], 500])] // 
  Apply[Association] // Dataset
```

You will see that as you click the next button it moves around. You have to constantly very slightly adjust the mouse to click browse through.

Comment: I see your problem, why don't you use the scrollbars above/below the scrollbar on the left? Those seem to not move around...

Comment: @AlbertRetey The scrollbar does not page. The actual `Dataset` is very large and paging is the way I need to navigate it.

Comment: ah, ok, didn't notice that difference...